# Calculate how many elements of this two-dimensional array exceed the arithmetic mean of all elements of this array

Tags: python

I need to calculate how many elements of a two-dimensional array exceed the arithmetic mean of all elements of this array

i need do this with this array

```
array = [[1, 5, 7, 3, 2], [2, 4 ,1 ,6, 8]]
```

Comment: What did you try to do? What errors did you get? How did you calculate the mean? Show your work.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please show your code and expected output. Also, be careful when talking about arrays in Python. What you have are lists

Answer (score 2):

Use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

array = [[1, 5, 7, 3, 2], [2, 4 ,1 ,6, 8]]

# convert to numpy array
a = np.array(array)

# get True for values above mean and count with sum
out = (a>a.mean()).sum()
# 5
```

In pure python:

```
from statistics import mean

avg = mean([x for l in array for x in l])
# 3.9

out = sum(1 for l in array for x in l if x>avg)
# 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different interpretation of the question. The assumption is that the output should be the number of values in each sub-list that exceed the mean for that same sub-list.

```
lists = [[1, 5, 7, 3, 2], [2, 4 ,1 ,6, 8]]

for e in lists:
    mean = sum(e) / len(e)
    print(sum(v > mean for v in e))
```

**Output:**

```
2
2
```